# SQL Server - query returns duplicate records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the below code:

```
select 
    b.ArpAccNo AS [Debtor no.]
    ,b.ArpAccName AS [Debtor name]
    ,a.TransDate
    ,d.InvoiceNumber
    ,a.ExtDocNo
    ,a.OrgAmt
    ,c.SettleAmt
    ,a.PostDate
    ,a.EqualisedPer
from 
    arptrans a 
inner join 
    ArpAccount AS b ON a.ArpAccId = b.ArpAccId
inner join 
    ArpEq AS c ON a.ArpTransId = c.CrArpTransId
inner join 
    JobInvoice AS d ON a.ArpAccId = d.DebtorId
where  
    a.CompId = '103'
    and ARPTransID IN (SELECT CrArpTransID 
                       FROM ArpEq 
                       WHERE ArpEq.EqDate >= '2019-03-21 00:00:00.000' 
                         AND ArpEq.EqDate <= '2019-03-31 00:00:00.000')
```

This query returns the below dataset:

[image]

This is duplicating the records many times.

I'm looking for advice on the best way to remove these duplicates?

All help much appreciated.

Comment: A quick answer is use distinct. However you must elaborate on what exactly you define as duplicate records, in order to have a more appropriate solution

Comment: I don't see any duplicate rows? Could you point out which rows you consider to be duplicates and why.

Comment: Check out: [Bad Habits to kick - using table alias like a,b,c,d or t1,t2,t3](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Can you post your schema definitions and the relationships? Obviously your `JOIN`s are not right here. And I see no reason for the subquery in the `WHERE` clause when you have that table with an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Posting a broken query without telling us what you want to accomplish will not help us help you.

Comment: Also I don't see any duplications.  All rows are different from each other.

Comment: apologies it maybe is in my description wrongly. I would like to try and roll up the invoice numbers so for all invoices that are the same i get one amount for each equalised date

Answer (score 0):

There are no duplicates here, all sixteen rows have unique values for all columns compared to all other rows.

I see one set of b.column values, one set of a.values, four different d.InvoiceNumber's, and four different c.SettleAmt values.  Since there are no SUM values in this query, that would imply that (1 A/B rows) x (4 c rows) x (4 d rows) = 16, and there sixteen rows in your return set.   If you query all tables for the JOIN criteria columns it'll likely prove that.

So, please eyeball the InvoiceNumber and SettleAmt columns, and explain for us in detail how you would like them to render.

{edit}  Another possibility is that there is a fat-finger in the JOIN..ON criteria, or the ON block does not contain all columns that define the unique relationship between tables.

Comment: apologies it maybe is in my description wrongly.  I would like to try and roll up the invoice numbers so for all invoices that are the same i get one amount for each equalised date.